# How to access OOP plugin function inside themes or other plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, oop

first of all I'm really sorry if the title of the question doesn't explain everything. Anyways here's what I was looking for.

I'm creating a WordPress plugin with OOP concept. So, I've codes like this

```
class somePlugin {
 //constructor goes here
 public function is_it_safe() {
  if( true ) {
   return true;
  } else {
   return false;
  } 
 }
}
```

**Please Note:** the above code is just an example. So, it may not make any sense.

So, now what I want is to make sure the `is_it_safe()` function can easily be called within other themes or plugins without even knowing the class or creating an object of the class. Is it possible?

I want the `is_it_safe()` function to be used by others easily without even doing `somePlugin::is_it_safe()`.

I'm not sure if it is possible or not. But if it is possible, if anyone can help, it would be heally helpful.

Comment: I didn't test it but try doing a trick. Create a file e.x. **my-function.php** and create a function e.x. `myplugin_is_it_safe()` which calls `somePlugin::is_it_safe()`. Then include that file to your main plugin file. Now when you activate your plugin, `myplugin_is_it_safe()` function should be available so as `is_it_safe()` method. I hope you know what I mean. And again, I didn't test it so I don't know if it does work

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Amazing I was also thinking trying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

No. You always have to refer to the instance of the class.